# Removing items from list if is not in '<a href'?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have data stored in a list like the following:

```
date_name = [<a href="/president/washington/speeches/speech-3455">Proclamation of Neutrality (April 22, 1793)</a>,
<a class="transcript" href="/president/washington/speeches/speech-3455">Transcript</a>, 
<a href="/president/washington/speeches/speech-3456">Fifth Annual Message to Congress (December 3, 1793)</a>, 
<a class="transcript" href="/president/washington/speeches/speech-3456">Transcript</a>, 
<a href="/president/washington/speeches/speech-3721">Proclamation against Opposition to Execution of Laws and Excise Duties in Western Pennsylvania (August 7, 1794)</a>]
```

These are not `str` elements inside `date_name`. I'm trying to get `Proclamation of Neutrality (April 22, 1793)`, `Fifth Annual Message to Congress (December 3, 1793)`, and `Proclamation against Opposition to Execution of Laws and Excise Duties in Western Pennsylvania (August 7, 1794)`, so that I can get the dates from each of those speeches. I want to do this for 900+ speeches. Here's the code I've been trying, as it worked for a similar problem I had in another list comprehension scenario:

```
url = 'http://www.millercenter.org/president/speeches'

connection = urllib2.urlopen(url)
html = connection.read()
date_soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
date_name = date_soup.find_all('a')
del date_name[:203]         # delete extraneous html before first link (for obama 4453)

# do something with the following list comprehensions
dater = [tag.get('<a href=') for tag in date_name if tag.get('<a href=') is not None]

# remove all items in list that don't contain '<a href=', as this string is unique
# to the elements in date_name that I want
speeches_dates = [_ for _ in dater if re.search('<a href=',_)]
```

However, I get an empty set with the `dater` variable process, so I'm unable to move forward to construct `speeches_dates`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you see is a `ResultSet` - a list of `Tag` instances. When you print a `Tag`, you get an HTML string representation. What you need is to get texts:

```
date_name = date_soup.find_all('a')[:203]
print([item.get_text(strip=True) for item in date_name])
```

Plus, from what I understand, you need the links to the speeches (in the main content that contain dates). In this case, instead of locating all of the `a` tags, you need to make your locator more specific:

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://www.millercenter.org/president/speeches'

date_soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(url), "lxml")
speeches = date_soup.select('div#listing div.title a[href*=speeches]')

for speech in speeches:
    text = speech.get_text(strip=True)
    print(text)
```

Prints:

```
Acceptance Speech at the Democratic National Convention (August 28, 2008)
Remarks on Election Night (November 4, 2008)
Inaugural Address (January 20, 2009)
...
Talk to the Cherokee Nation (August 29, 1796)
Farewell Address (September 19, 1796)
Eighth Annual Message to Congress (December 7, 1796)
```

Comment: Outstanding solution. It's incredible you were able to do all of that in 5 minutes, while it's taken me forever just mucking around with list comprehensions..